# Having trouble creating Histogram from data off a CSV, object has no attribute or 'Series' object is not callable?

Tags: python-3.x, histogram, altair

So I'm just trying to created a simple histogram of the masses found in my data, I followed this simple example:

```
# importing libraries
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
  
# importing cars dataset
# form vega_datasets provided by altair
car_data  = data.cars()
  
# making the simple histogram on Acceleration
hist = alt.Chart(car_data).mark_bar().encode(x = 'Acceleration',
                                             y = 'count()')
# showing the histogram
hist.show()
```

but when I try it with my code:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

data = pd.read_csv('https://gwosc.org/eventapi/csv/GWTC/')

total_mass = data['total_mass_source']

mass = data.total_mass()

hist = alt.Chart(mass).mark_bar().encode(x = 'total_mass_source', y = 'count()')

hist.show()
```

I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ligo/LIGO/GWC/test.py", line 43, in <module>
    mass = data.total_mass()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/ligo/mambaforge/envs/igwn/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5989, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'total_mass'
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
(igwn) ligo@llcitadmins-MacBook-Pro GWC % python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ligo/LIGO/GWC/test.py", line 43, in <module>
    mass = data.total_mass_source()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
```

I've tried adjusting the names, I print out total_mass and i do get back the data I'm looking for.

```
(igwn) ligo@llcitadmins-MacBook-Pro GWC % python test.py
0      NaN
1      NaN
2      NaN
3      NaN
4      NaN
      ... 
88    43.9
89    50.6
90    61.9
91    21.2
92    55.0
```

so I know the data is there, is it because some of the fields are zero? Do I need to account for that?

Comment: the error is coming from the line `mass = data.total_mass()`. What do you want this line to do? `data` is a dataframe. I assume that *total_mass* is the name of a column, and so `data.total_mass` would select that column (the Series). Then this line of code tries to call that series, which can't be done, as the error says.

Comment: so i thought I was creating a dataframe mass that had the values i needed to use for my histogram, I guess i can just use this: data = pd.read_csv('https://gwosc.org/eventapi/csv/GWTC/')

mass = data['total_mass_source']

hist = alt.Chart(mass).mark_bar().encode(x = 'total_mass_source', y='count()')

hist.show(), it gives me this code now: ValueError: total_mass_source encoding field is specified without a type; the type cannot be automatically inferred because the data is not specified as a pandas.DataFrame.

Comment: Yes, `pandas.Series.plot.hist` should be able to give you a histogram just fine. You can do this directly with your dataframe `data` instead of saving a column to a new variable. `ax = data.plot.hist(column=["total_mass_source"], bins=12, alpha=0.5, figsize=(10, 8))` should do the trick.

Comment: Also, you can clean your data to drop NaNs or replace with another value if you would like.

Comment: oh ok I got, I was over thinking it, thanks!